# What font is used in this CoffeeSmith sign?

Tags: font-identification, serif

What is the font / typeface is it in the image? (or any similar ones)

[image]

[image]

Comment: For further research you may be able to square the image using the skew tool in Photoshop and then load it into [What the Font](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/)

Comment: It could be a Korean font that has support for the roman alphabet as well given CoffeeSmith is Korean.

Comment: We really do need a better photo. @Ilan Your edit (adding the second image) shows extra serifs which are not present in the physical letters.

Comment: @AndrewLeach they are present, I checked every single serif :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks similar to [Minerva Modern Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/minerva-modern/) with some (quite a few) modifications:

[image]

Other similar fonts include [Optima Demi-bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/optima/) and [URW Classico](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/classico/).

**Edit:** user Ilmari Karonen in the comments just pointed out this font, [Serif Gothic Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/itc-serif-gothic/bold/), which looks very similar apart from the stroke emphasis:

[image]

Maybe you can combine the shape of the top one and the serifs and details of the bottom one...

Comment: Not a bad match for the general appearance, but the details are pretty far off. The font in the picture clearly has [flare](http://www.myfonts.com/search/tag:"flare+serif"/fonts/) or [spur serifs](http://www.myfonts.com/search/tag:"spur+serif"/fonts/), somewhat like [ITC Serif Gothic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/itc-serif-gothic/) (which has the serifs and a similar "m", although it is not otherwise very similar at all) or [Mythica](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/k-type/mythica/) (which is closer in general appearance, but still off in several details).

Comment: Serif Gothic actually looks very similar apart from the stroke emphasis!  Mind if I put it in my answer?

Comment: Sure, go ahead.

Comment: Fairly certain that `coffee` and `smith` are different typefaces.